# Removing and attaching USB audio Jabra headset on Windows 7 SP1 can cause problems with network. How to investigate it?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, rtp, directsound

I work on specialized voip application.
It uses TLS as signalling channel and (S)RTP as media channel in calls.

There is a audio output module written that uses DirectSound to play & capture.
Audio module is resistant to audio errors. If it detects smth wrong -
1) the problem audio device is closed
2) main application is notified about problem 
3) customer can select another audio device.
Works good most of time.

But sometimes the sequence "remove / wait 10-20 seconds / insert USB Jabra headset" results in interest thing. There is no more incoming RTP packets or they are corrupted.
OS can send ICMP reports about non available port to remote peer even.

I checked with DevPartner and DrMemory error checkers - but there weren't hints in their reports.

I think it can be driver or Windows issue. It is reproducible on other systems sometimes.

The question - how can I investigate this issue? Maybe there are tools that show audio driver activity inside Windows?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have a lot on traffic on your network adapter? I wonder if you can suffer from Network Throttling http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2007/08/27/1833290.aspx - quite some unobvious thing.

Comment: Not too much. Idle Skype + Gmail + G722 stream in call.